# Bisection Method does not converge

Tags: fortran, bisection

I'm trying to implement Bisection Method with Fortran 90 to get solution, accurate to within 10^-5 for 3x - e^x = 0 for 1 <= x <= 2

This is the code that I came up with, but when I run the code it just list .1.5000000000000000 100 times.

How should I fix this code so that I can keep applying bisection method correctly until I get to a number around 10^-5?

```
program main
implicit none
double precision a,b, TOL
integer maxN
a = 1.d0
b = 2.d0
TOL = .000001d0
maxN = 100
call bisection(a, b, TOL, maxN)
end program

function f(x)
double precision x,f
f = 3*x - e**x
end function

subroutine bisection(a, b, TOL,maxN)
implicit none
double precision a, b, TOL
integer maxN

double precision p, fp, fa, fb, f
integer j

p = (a+b)/2.d0
do j =1, maxN
fp = f(p)
fa = f(a)
fb = f(b)

    if ( 0.5d0 * (b-a) < TOL) then
            print *, "Reach desired tolerance",p
            return

    end if

    if (fa*fp <0) then
            b = p
    else if (fb*fp < 0) then
            a = p
    end if

    p = (a+b)/2.d0
    print *,j,p
end do
end subroutine bisection
```

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Use tag fortran for all Fortran questions. Add a specific version where necessary. Note that Fortran 90 is a 25 years old and quite obsolete version.

Comment: It is also good to use more indentation in your codes.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is actually not with your algorithm, but rather in how you calculate `f`. Because you have not specified `implicit none` in the function, the compiler allowed `e**x` to slip through, even though Fortran doesn't define `e` as you would have liked.

When you correct the function as follows, the program works fine:

```
function f(x)
  implicit none
  double precision x,f
  f = 3*x - exp(x)
end function f
```

This is a good lesson to use implicit none *everywhere*.